# How do I trade weapons with someone?

Tags: gears-of-war-4

Someone walked up to me and held out their Lancer in exchange for my Hammerburst in versus. How do I offer a trade like they did?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you get close to the other player so your facing each other and you aim at them with LT and press X, this promts the other player to accept or decline the trade or you can cancel the offer with B